# 12.04 LTS 32bit or 64bit on dell sudio 15

Tags: 12.04

I have a processor of 64bit and 3gb ram, which version of ubuntu 12.04 LTS will be better & stable, 32 or 64. Dont know about UEFI, if that is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

UEFI Will Allow you to stick with only one Operating system in your Base system , And it Secure from boot attacks ,Make PC faster boot time and from hibernation , Support for large drive spaces , Supports for most recent 64 bit drivers and etc ... And As you told that your machine was 64 bit Processor install the 64 bit to get full performance,

```
Ubuntu 12.04 Lts 64 bit
```